# mySQL error #1054 Why is my inner join not working? (Rookie Level)

Tags: mysql, inner-join, mysql-error-1054

```
 SELECT `orders.customerNumber`, `orders.orderNumber`, `orders.orderDate`, `payments.customerNumber`, `payments.amount`
From `Orders`
INNER JOIN `Payments`
ON Payments.customerNumber=Orders.customerNumber;
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. Syntax issue perhaps?
Thank you for your time, I really appreciate it.

Comment: If there was a syntax issue then the error message would say so.

Comment: Just remove all those misused backticks

Comment: Good to know. This is my first attempt at a join.

Comment: removed ticks, same error

Comment: Perhaps you forgot to create the table.

Comment: The Primary Key for Payments is customerNumber
The Primary Key for Orders is orderNumber
The Foreign Key for Orders is customerNumber

Comment: If you want some help with this, you'll probably need to provide the error message together with the CREATE TABLE statements

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it
      SELECT Orders.customerNumber, Orders.orderNumber, Orders.orderDate, Payments.amount
      FROM Orders
      INNER JOIN Payments ON Orders.customerNumber=Payments.customerNumber;